# String comparison - Android

Tags: java, android, string

I'm unable to compare two strings using the following code:

I have a string named "gender" which will have "Male" or "Female" as its value.

```
if(gender == "Male")
   salutation ="Mr.";
if(gender == "Female")
   salutation ="Ms.";
```

This didn't work, so I tried the following:

```
String g1="Male";
String g2="Female";
if(gender.equals(g1))
   salutation ="Mr.";
if(gender.equals(g2))
   salutation ="Ms.";
```

Again, it didn't work.
Can someone please tell me how to compare string values using the if statement.

Comment: Have you get solution from answers ?

Comment: If that is not working, it is because gender is something else. Add this to figure it what is `Log.d("GENDER", gender)`

Answer (score 98):

Try this

```
if(gender.equals("Male"))
 salutation ="Mr.";
if(gender.equals("Female"))
 salutation ="Ms.";
```

Also remove `;`(semi-colon ) in your if statement

```
if(gender.equals(g1));
```

In Java, one of the most common mistakes newcomers meet is using == to compare Strings. You have to remember, == compares the object references, not the content.

Comment: If you explain why, I'll +1 this :)

Comment: Look at your code carefully and remove the ; at the end of both the if statements.

Comment: Sorry, i wasn't using ; after the if stmt in my actual code, error while typing the question here!

Comment: @RaghavKumar What's the input?

Comment: The input for the sting 'gender' is coming from a spinner which is in my MainActivity.java file. I have checked the value of variable 'gender', no problem with that, but unable to use it the way i want

Comment: @RaghavKumar then try out other solution or update your code with that `MainActivity.java`

Comment: For null-safety, I always put the constant on the left side: `if("Male".equals(gender))`

Answer (score 13):

String unlike int or other numeric variables are compared in Java differently than other languages.

To compare Strings in Java (android) it is used the method .compareTo();

so the code should be like this:

```
if(gender.compareTo("Male")==0){
   salutation ="Mr.";
}
if(gender.compareTo("Female")==0){
   salutation ="Ms.";
}
```

Answer (score 10):

In Java we don't compare string as you are doing above...
Here is String comparison...

```
    if (gender.equalsIgnoreCase("Male")) {
        salutation = "Mr.";
    } else if (gender.equalsIgnoreCase("Female")) {
        salutation = "Ms.";
    }
```

Answer (score 8):

I think the above mentioned answer is correct.Because == is for testing whether two strings are the same object,whereas .equals() tests whether two strings have the same value.

Comment: This is a better explanation why not to use ==

Comment: there is no "above" answer, for the order varies with number of votes.  please edit and specify, if possible.  tks

Answer (score 4):

The == operator checks to see if two objects are exactly the same object. Two strings may be different objects, but have the same value (have exactly the same characters in them). Use the .equals() method to compare strings for equality.

http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/data/strings/12stringcomparison.html

Answer (score 4):

Your `gender == "Male"` is actually comparing the object references for the object `gender` and a different object `Male`. What you have to use is the `.equals()` method to compare the value of the objects.

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
String g1="Male";
    String g2="Female";
    if(gender.equals(g1))
       salutation ="Mr.";
    if(gender.equals(g2))
       salutation ="Ms.";
```

you were ending your if statement  `if(gender.equals(g1));` <<--- here by adding ";"

Answer (score 3):

```
String g1="Male";
String g2="Female";
String salutation="";
String gender="Male";
if(gender.toLowerCase().trim().equals(g1.toLowerCase().trim()));
   salutation ="Mr.";
if(gender.toLowerCase().trim().equals(g2.toLowerCase().trim()));
   salutation ="Ms.";
```

Answer (score 3):

try this.

```
        String g1 = "Male";
        String g2 = "Female";
        String gender = "Male";
        String salutation = "";
        if (gender.equalsIgnoreCase(g1))

            salutation = "Mr.";
        else if (gender.equalsIgnoreCase(g2))

            salutation = "Ms.";
        System.out.println("Welcome " + salutation);
```

Output:

```
Welcome Mr.
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
if(gender.equals("Male")){
 salutation ="Mr.";
}
else if(gender.equals("Female")){
 salutation ="Ms.";
}
```

Remember, not to use `;` after `if` statement.

Answer (score 2):

In addition if you want to compare if two strings are different, you can use :

```
String mystring = "something";
!mystring.equals("whatever")
```

It will return true!

Answer (score 0):

```
if(gender.equals(g1)); <---
if(gender == "Female"); <---
```

You have semicolon after if.REMOVE IT.

Answer (score 0):

Actually every code runs well here, but your probleme probably come from your `gender` variable. Did you try to do a simple `System.out.println(gender);` before the comparaison ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use, contentEquals() function. It may help you..

Answer (score 0):

This one work for me:

```
 if (email.equals("fahim@gmail.com") && pass.equals("123ss") ){
        Toast.makeText(this,"Logged in",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else{

        Toast.makeText(this,"Logged out",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually we could help better if we could see what is the input coming ***gender***

However you can try following, maybe it's a case issue, like the incoming ***gender*** is *male* instead of *Male*

```
if(gender.equalsIgnoreCase("male"){
    salutation = "Mr.";
} else if(gender.equalsIgnoreCase("female"){
    salutation = "Ms.";
}
```

Or if this didn't worked, try getting the **gender** and let us know what it is, so we can help better.
You can print ***gender*** like this

```
System.out.println(gender);
```

You may see the output on the Console on your IDE

Answer (score -1):

Try it:

```
if (Objects.equals(gender, "Male")) {
    salutation ="Mr.";
} else if (Objects.equals(gender, "Female")) {
    salutation ="Ms.";
}
```